# 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is to be installed. However it is already installed

Tags: libraries

I would like to install some development libraries on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev

From the output of the command I read that packages have unmet dependencies:

 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but
 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is to be installed
                    Depends: libncurses5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is to be installed
                    Depends: libtinfo-dev (= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed  libnss3-dev : Depends: libnss3 (=
 2:3.35-2ubuntu2) but 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7 is to be installed 
 libreadline-dev : Depends: libtinfo-dev but it is not going to be
 installed  libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4) but
 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5 is to be installed
               Recommends: libssl-doc but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
 packages.

So I run the following command to install the libtinfo5:

    sudo apt-get install libtinfo5

However libinfo5 is already the newest version (6.1-1ubuntu.1.18.04)
```

Why the dependency is unmet if the libtinfo5 is already in its newest version.

Comment: Fix broken : `sudo apt install -f` .... And always refresh / update the package list before installing packages : `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
You're trying to install

```
libncurses5-dev
```

which depends

```
libtinfo5 version 6.1-1ubuntu.1
```

but in your system is installed version

```
6.1-1ubuntu.1.18.04
```

You need to downgrade the libinfo5 version via

```
 apt install libtinfo5=6.1-1ubuntu.1
```

**BUT BE REALLY CAREFUL**: in my system an attempt of downgrade of this package prompt the uninstallation of pretty much everything, obviously breaking the whole system.

Actually I have not figured out how to downgrade this package without broke the system.

***EDIT***: using `apitude` instead on `apt` I was able to downgrade all the necessary packages.
Must be said I had got to rid all the dependencies by myself.
Using `aptitude -s install <package-name>=<version>` should help to get rid of it.

The `-s` option allow to simulate what can happen to the system.